# Waiting for other processors to finish their tasks in MPI

Tags: mpi

Using MPI, how do you wait for threads to finish?

For example:

```
for (int i = localstart; i < localend; i++)
{
    // do stuff that is computationally intensive
}
// I need to wait for all other threads to finish here
if (rank == 0) do_something();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by threads you meant processes/ranks, then the answer is `MPI_Barrier`.

But look at the other collective operations too: they might make sense in your application, and offer better performance than hand-coding communication.  For example, you could use `MPI_Allgather` to communicate all data to all ranks, and so on.

If you meant threads (like pthreads), then you'd have to use whatever the threading library offers.

Comment: I meant processes/ranks.  Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.